# API to retrieve Promo Codes for an App from iTunes?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Is there any API which lets me generate and retrieve promo codes of an App from iTunes?

Please let me know.

Comment: I believe they can only be manually generated from within iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iTunes Connect you can generate promo codes. There is no known API, so the answer to your question is **no**. That kind of answer does come around once and a while ;)

Note that you can only generate 50 promo codes for each version of an app. Most people send them to reviewers.

Because of that limit, most promotional giveaways are done by temporarily dropping the price of your app. You can change prices instantaneously through iTunes Connect, like screenshots before the recent change to prevent scammers!